# How to read hex numbers like this 0x7c00009d?

Tags: c

Hi I am wondering if anyone could explain how to read hex numbers like 0x7c00009d i.e. how does it look like in binary form with all the zeroes?

Comment: To read: `long x; if(scanf("%lx", &x) == 1) Success();`

Answer (score 4):

Each hex digit has a four-bit equivalent

```
0x0 = 0000b
0x1 = 0001b
0x2 = 0010b
0x3 = 0011b
0x4 = 0100b
0x5 = 0101b
0x6 = 0110b
0x7 = 0111b
0x8 = 1000b
0x9 = 1001b
0xA = 1010b
0xB = 1011b
0xC = 1100b
0xD = 1101b
0xE = 1110b
0xF = 1111b
```

To convert to binary just replace each digit with its equivalent.  In your example:

```
0x7c00009d = 0111 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 1001 1101
```

or

```
01111100000000000000000010011101b
```

The 'b' suffix at the end serves to indicate this is a binary number.

Answer (score 2):

Hex numbers are positional numeral system with **base 16** which **uses 0-9 to represent values from zero to nine** and **A,B,C,D,E,F to represent values ten to fifteen**.

Hex numbers are **prefixed as 0x**. After prefix, each number can be read as in between 0 to F.

Hex number: **0x**7c00009d

Binary Form: 0111 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 1001 1101

Check out conversion and Hexadecimal to Binary Conversion Chart at

http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-binary-converter